# git and C++ workflow, how to handle object and archive files?

Tags: c++, git, workflow

I use git to interface with an SVN repository. I have several git branches for the different projects I work on.

Now, whenever I switch from one branch to another using 'git checkout ', all the compiled executables and object files from the previous branch are still there. What I would like to see is that switching from branch A to B results in a tree with all object files and binaries from the last time I worked on branch B.

Is there a way to handle this without creating multiple git repositories?

**Update:** I understand that executables and binaries should not end up in the repository. I'm a bit disappointed in the fact that all the branching stuff in git is useless to me, as it turns out I'll have to clone my proxy git repository for every branch I want to start. Something I already did for SVN and hoped to avoid with git. Of course, I don't have to do it, but it would result in me doing a new make most of the time after switching between branches (not fun).

Comment: You should checkout different branches to different directories, or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: Why do you want executables and binaries in source control at all?

Comment: As is pointed in an answer a good solution is to build in a separate folder that where the sources are. But cloning local git repositories is really fast, so it may not be that bad.

Comment: An external build directory is only useful if it updates to reflect his branch. Otherwise it's no better than make clean.

Comment: The VCSs I've used have ways to exclude certain file types, so it would be possible to set some sort of ignore flag on *.o files (the actual executables in Unix-based systems would be harder, typically lacking an extension).

Comment: why not have different outside build directories, one for each branch?  Inside the branch there could be a symlink that goes to the appropriate build directory.  I'm just shooting from the hip here, but I can't think of a reason that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a full context, not just the branch... which is *generally* out of scope for a version control tool. The best way to do that is to use multiple repositories.

Don't worry about the inefficiency of that though... Make your second repository a clone of the first. Git will automatically use links to avoid having multiple copies on disk.

**Here's a hack to give you want you want**

Since you have separate obj directories, you could modify your Makefiles to make the base location dynamic using something like this:

```
OBJBASE = `git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1\//'`
OBJDIR = "$(OBJBASE).obj"
# branch master: OBJBASE == "master/", OBJDIR == "master/.obj"
# non-git checkout: OBJBASE == "", OBJDIR == ".obj"
```

That will but your branch name into OBJBASE, which you can use to build your actual objdir location from. I'll leave it to you to modify it to fit your environment and make it friendly to non-git users of your Makefiles.

Answer (score 6):

This is not git or svn specific - you should have your compiler and other tools direct the output of intermediate files like .o files to directories that are not under version control.

Comment: Is this standard practice? Currently our tree is divided in separate src directories for every module with accompanying obj and lib directories. Any pointers on how to do this differently (in a standard way)?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where in the tree they are so long as the contents are excluded from control by mechanisms like svn:ignore

Comment: This won't make the object files match his checkout. He's trying to avoid 'make clean' on branch change.

Answer (score 5):

To keep multiple checkouts of the same repo, you can use git --work-tree.
For example,

```
mkdir $BRANCH.d
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$BRANCH.index git --work-tree $BRANCH.d checkout $BRANCH
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set your IDE compiler to generate all private temporary files (.class and so on) in `<output>\branchName\...`.

By configuration your compilation setting branch by branch, you can register the name of the branch in the output directory path.

That way, even if though private files remain when you `git checkout`, your project on the new branch is ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

In the `contrib/` directory of the `git` distribution, there is a script called `git-new-workdir` that allows you to checkout multiples branches in different directories without cloning your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Those files aren't tracked by Git or Subversion, so they're left alone on the assumption that they are of some use to you.

I just do my checkouts in different directories. Saves me the trouble of doing cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

A make clean should not be necessary because files that are different between different branches get checked out with the actual date!!!

This means that if your Makefile is correct, only those object-files, libs and executables are compiled again that really changed because of the checkout. Which is exactly the reason a makefile is there in the first place.

The exception is if you need to switch compiler options or even compilers in different branches. In that case probably git-new-workdir is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

**If the compiled executables are files that have been checked in**
then git stash solves the problem.

```
[compile]
git stash save "first branch"
git checkout other_branch
[Fiddle with your code]
[compile]
git stash save "second branch"
git checkout first_branch
git stash apply [whatever index your "first branch" stash has]
# alternatively git stash pop [whatever index...]
```

**If the compiled executables are files that have not and will not be checked in**
then simply add them to .gitignore