# git working on two branches simultaneously

Tags: git, branch

I have a project with many branches.

I would like to work on **several** branches simultaneously without switching back and forth with `git checkout`.

Is there any way I can do that besides copying the whole repository somewhere else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple working directories with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git)

Comment: Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will officially support this with the new command `git checkout --to=<path>`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30186843/6309).

Comment: Actually, the command will be `git worktree add <path> [<branch>]` (Git 2.5 rc2)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) supports this feature!

If you have a git repo `cool-app`, cd to root (`cd cool-app`), run `git worktree add ../cool-app-feature-A feature/A`. This checks out the branch `feature/A` in it's own new dedicated directory, `cool-app-feature-A`.

That replaces an older script `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir`, with a more robust mechanism where those "linked" working trees are actually recorded in the main repo new `$GIT_DIR/worktrees` folder (so that work on any OS, including Windows).

Again, once you have cloned a repo (in a folder like `/path/to/myrepo`), you can add worktrees for different branches in *different* independent paths (`/path/to/br1`, `/path/to/br2`), while having those working trees linked to the main repo history (no need to use a `--git-dir` option anymore)

See more at "**[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)**".

And once you have created a [worktree, you can move or remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331132/6309) (with Git 2.17+, Q2 2018).

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer, since 2.5.X is now the recommended version, even for windows http://i.imgur.com/oQvUhVl.png https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Just to confirm, the process would be same even if I already have created branches in the past and now, want to work on them simultaneously? Thanks :)

Comment: @Milan Yes: you can chackout wortrees for existing past branches.

Comment: @VonC, thanks for such a quick reply. One more thing I noticed is that after running the `git add worktree ......` command for two different branches, every time it said: "HEAD is not at <commit> <commit message>". However, there can be only one `HEAD` right? How there can be two `HEADs`? Thanks!

Comment: @Milan What version of Git are you using? (on which OS?). As I documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599305/6309, `git worktree add` has been improved in recent versions of Git.

Comment: @VonC, I'm using `git version 2.17.1`  on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. Oh, I see there is a `HEAD` in each worktree. Thanks a lot for sharing your link. It's very helpful. I was also thinking about how I would delete the worktrees I created but after skimming through your answer, I think I would get the solution, whenever required. Thanks again!

Comment: @Milan You are most welcome. 2.17 sounds too old for me. I wasn't born yet ;)

Comment: @VonC, oh that sounds weird because I even tried updating it using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install --only-upgrade git` but it says `git is already the newest version (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7).` ! Is there anything wrong my system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224006/discussion-between-vonc-and-milan).

Comment: @VonC this throws the error: `fatal: ../cool-app-feature-A: '../cool-app-feature-A' is outside repository`.

Comment: @y_159 what git version and OS are you using?

Comment: @VonC Ubuntu 18.04 and git version 2.17.1.

Comment: @y_159 OK. Try and upgrade to 2.30.2 with ppa (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309), and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @VonC `fatal: ../cool-app-feature-A: '../cool-app-feature-A' is outside repository at '/home/<user>/cool-app'`

Comment: The error description is quite different from earlier one.

Comment: @VonC with the above mentioned link, I was able to install git 2.33.0 version.

Comment: @y_159 ok, what command do you type?

Comment: `user@user-VirtualBox:~/repo$ git add worktree ../cool-app-feature <branch_name> fatal: ../cool-app-feature: '../cool-app-feature' is outside repository at '/home/user/repo'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237881/discussion-between-vonc-and-y-159).

Answer (score 41):

Take a look at [$GIT_SRC_DIR/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir).

According to the [commit logs](https://github.com/Khan/git-new-workdir/commit/88e4295fa435a339a39afecfed058e80a24ff35d) from a port of this repository:

> a simple script to create a working directory that uses symlinks to
> point at an exisiting repository.  This allows having different
> branches in different working directories but all from the same
> repository.

Comment: And the similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655202/git-and-c-workflow-how-to-handle-object-and-archive-files/1889179#1889179

Comment: I know this is old, but could you provide some explanation please.

Comment: @dav_i: Like [this](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f01748d51b530c297eeb5a0ece9af923d5db937) ?

Comment: @StefanNäwe Ah I was confused - too early in the morning... updated your answer with link.

Answer (score 2):

Git supports multiple worktree at the same time. For more information see:

- [Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git)
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

How ever it is very hard to support multiple worktree with IDs. For example this is an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477475) in JGet (eclipse ID) to support worktree.

So, you have to manage project manually (command line) with lots of problems or work with a single worktree in an IDE.

Comment: As of now, this answer is not correct. Please update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scalable version of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186843/9962007) (upvoted), with sequentially named branches (`app1..app10`).

Note we should try to *avoid duplicate checkout* (here: by checking out the `master` branch, which will not be covered by `git worktree add`):

```
$ git checkout master && for NUM in {1..10}; do git worktree add ~/git/<repo-name>/app$NUM app$NUM; done
```

Comment: Nicely done. Upvoted. I would just use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of `git checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest my small script http://www.redhotchilipython.com/en_posts/2013-02-01-clone-per-feature.html

It will do git clone and replace the config (to "look" at original repo, so pull/push will go into "main" repo) basically, but it's simple enough to serve an abstraction from actual bootstrapping.

Answer (score -3):

Not really as Git only supports to have *one* working copy of the repository data within the repository directory.

If you want to commit/pull to the same repository with two different working copies, you could create a *bare* repository and clone it to two *working copies*.

Whenever you have finished something, you simply push to the *"main"* bare repository.

Some hints:

`man git-clone`

`git clone --bare`

Comment: _"Git only supports to have one working copy of the repository data"_ 
 -1 Not true, see the answer about `git-new-workdir`.

Comment: That's nice idea. Just clone it twice.