# Checking out the branches of a git repository into sub folders?

Tags: git, directory, branch, subdirectory

Is it possible to take a repository (such as CakePHP1.x @ http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x) and checkout the master plus branches into sub-folders?

For example, my desired folder structure would be like this:

> cakephp1.x
>
> |------ 1.2
>
> |------ 1.3
>
> |------ master

I know you can use **git checkout -t origin/branch** to switch between branches from a cloned repository, but I was wondering if there was a way to do the above without having to clone the repository and rename repeatedly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
mkdir cakephp
cd cakephp
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x.git master
cd master
git checkout -t origin/1.2
git checkout -t origin/1.3
cd ..
git clone master 1.2
git clone master 1.3
cd 1.2
git checkout -t origin/1.2
```

The two local `git clone` operations will be very quick because they will use hard links to share most of the repository data.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I was wondering though - if I do a 'git pull' on the master, this works great - how would I pull down updates on the 1.2 / 1.3 branches?

Comment: After doing a `git pull` on the master, do a `git pull` on the 1.2/1.3 branches, which will pull from master (due to *their* tracking branches). Or, you could add github as a new remote to the branch repositories and pull directly. Git is like Perl - there's more than one way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

cloning the repository is not a very big deal. If it happends on a local filesystem most of the repository contents is cloned via hard links.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048470/git-working-on-two-branches-simultaneously/2051503#2051503) ?!