# github links to project files

Tags: html, git, github

I have a project hosted at github. Inside the project there are various html files for the documentation. Is it possible to link these files somewhere? It is not possible to use the links to the raw files since the mime type is text/plain such that browsers will not show them correctly.

I have also tried to github pages but I do not know how I create link to the html files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350432/how-to-create-github-pages-from-a-projects-documentation) is addressing the same issue. Basically, you create a gh-pages branch, move your documentation into that branch, and then re-add the documentation to the main project as a submodule.

The submodule step is only necessary if you need to have your documentation files available in your main branch.

Update:
Since you're dealing with generated documentation, the process outlined in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290760/git-is-cross-branch-reference-possible) might be a better fit. If your documentation generation process isn't configurable to output to multiple places, you may have to add a post-build event to copy the docs from one directory to another.

Comment: Hmm, this means that I have to change the project structure. I am not sure if I want this. I have tried the other way, using the master branch as a submodule but it does not work due to some limitations of git...

Comment: Is the documentation generated? And does it need to be in the main project?

Comment: Yes, it is [this project](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2). The documentation is generated and there are links to other source and example files.

Comment: See the update to my answer - I found another question where someone implemented a solution to a similar problem with generated docs.

Comment: Ok, that should to work. Is is more or less a manual solution but is should solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is you could load them in with AJAX and then print them out as HTML using jQuery.