# git-flow same working directory for different branches?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm new to `git-flow` but have worked in other version control systems (notably perforce) and used branching strategies very similar to git-flow. I'm not very familiar with the git CLI, so I use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) and of late [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

I've set up git-flow on a client machine (remote/origin is a bare repo on a server) and I now see that there are two branches on my client - `develop` and `master`. But SourceTree never asked me for a working directory for the `develop`. From what I see it is dynamically switching branches (fetching from appropriate remote branch).

My question - Is this the right way of working with git? I mean what if I am working in a `feature/*` branch and need to work in a `hotfix/*` branch. My changes to the `feature/*` branch would get lost if I did not stash them before the switch.

In a past life the way we handled branches was to have a different `root/working` folders for each branch and work on them in isolation without affecting work in any other branch.

Can I do the same with git i.e. clone each branch at a different working folder. More importantly would this scheme work with git-flow as implemented in SourceTree/SmartGit?

Comment: What is the problem with stashing the branches if you have to do a quick change in another branch?

Comment: @Pigueiras it a problem if I want to work simultaneously on two or more branches. It is not uncommon for me to have two instances of eclipse/visual studio open simultaneously with source from both the develop and the dot fix branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048470/git-working-on-two-branches-simultaneously ?

Comment: @Pigueiras Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Please put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: This is a duplicated question then, maybe you can flag your own question as a duplicate :). It's not a good thing to put an answer with just a link to another SO answer haha.