# call python code of different git branch other than the current repository without switching branch

Tags: python, git, gitpython

So, basically I have 2 versions of a project and for some users, I want to use the latest version while for others, I want to use older version. Both of them have same file names and multiple users will use it simultaneously. To accomplish this, I want to call function from different git branch without actually switching the branch.
Is there a way to do so?

for eg., when my current branch is `v1` and the other branch is `v2`; depending on the value of variable `flag`, call the function

```
if flag == 1:
    # import function f1() from branch v2
    return f1()
else:
    # use current branch v1
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you can explain why you need to do this e.g. why you can't have all the code you need on a single branch. This seems like an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TomDalton i have updated the question to explain the details

Comment: why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on *why* you need to do that, you can simply checkout your repo twice: once for branch1, and one for branch2 (without cloning twice).
See "[git working on two branches simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186843/6309)".

You can then make your script aware of its current path (`/path/to/branch1`), and relative path to the other branch (`../branch2/...`)

Comment: I cannot do this because the code is used parallely by multiple users. If I switch the branch, users for which flag is not 1 might also get the result of v2 branch

Comment: @proprius my answer is bout *not* switching the branch. The two branches are already there. If your code knows it, no branch switching of any kind is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* have both versions of the code present / accessible in order to invoke both versions of the code dynamically.

The by-far-simplest way to accomplish this is to have both versions of the code present in different locations, as in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39290774/1256452).

Since Python is what it is, though, you *could* dynamically extract specific versions of specific source files, compile them on the fly (using dynamic imports and temporary files, or `exec` and internal strings), and hence run code that does not show up in casual perusal of the program source.  I *do not* encourage this approach: it is difficult (though not very difficult) and error-prone, tends towards security holes, and is overall a terrible way to work unless you're writing something like a Python debugger or IDE.  But if this is what you want to do, you simply decompose the problem into:

- examine and/or extract specific files from specific commits (`git show`, `git cat-file -p`, etc.), and
- dynamically load or execute code from file in file system or from string in memory.

The first is a Git programming exercise (and is pretty trivial, `git show 1234567:foo.py` or `git show branch:foo.py`: you can redirect the output to a file using either shell redirection or Python's `subprocess` module), and when done with files, the second is a Python programming exercise of moderate difficulty: see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modules.html), paying particularly close attention to `importlib`.