# Git -- Keep `Master` and `branch` in the Same Folder

Tags: git

Should I put the `master` and other `branch` in separate folders?

For example, I have a folder called `myF/`. And I clone a project called `whatever`. And `whatever` is consist of two files -- `a.txt, b.txt`.

```
cd myF
git clone whatever
```

Then I create a branch called `feature0`.

```
git branch feature0
```

Now if I change anything to `a.txt` or `b.txt`, it will change both `master` and `feature0`.

Should I keep `master` untouched? And only change files in `feature0`?

Comment: Are you used to using SVN? Git doesn't work in the same way. It only ever has one copy of the files on disk. When you switch branches, it changes the existing directory structure to be that of the branch you are now on.

Comment: @adrianbanks I see. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should look into how git commits and branches work. Here's a good overview: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now if I change anything to `a.txt` or `b.txt`, it will change both `master` and `feature0`.

No it won't: it will be added and committed in the current branch (`feature0`)

```
x (master)
 \
  y (feature0)
```

Generally, you keep one working tree (one folder) for all branches and you switch the content of said working tree.

But since Git 2.5, you can indeed have *separate* working trees (one per branch) for *one* cloned repo: see [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) that I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186843/6309) and with more details, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309).